# Python only reading the if statement not any of the elif statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an old style adventure game in python and when i run the move command which adds +1 or -1 to the X or Y it will not check the elif statement.

I added a print just after the while True and found out that the code was only checking if the first statement was true and not checking the elif statements below it. I know the values change but it does not check them with any elif statements it only checks the if statement.

```
while True:
    if X == "0" and Y == "0":
        inp = input('You are in a dark room and cannot see much. describe items, collect, move')
        if inp == "describe items":
            print('The room has a key, and two doors.')
        if inp == "collect":
            Icollect = input('Which item do you want to collect')
            if Icollect == "key":
                Slot = input('You have 5 inventory slots, which one do you want to put the key into?')
                Inventory[1] = 'key'
        if inp == "move":
            Move = input('Which door do you want to go through the door in front or to the right of you?')
            if Move == "front":
                Y = int(Y) + 1
            if Move == "right":
                X = int(X) + 1
    elif X == "0" and Y == "1":
        inp = input('You have climbed a set of stairs and entered what looks like a study. describe items, inspect, move')
        if inp == "describe items":
            print('There is a bookcase and a door to the left and behind you.')
        if inp == "inspect":
            inspect = input('You can only inspect the bookcase')
            if inspect == "bookcase":
                print('The bookcase has fallen and revealed a third door to your right')
        if inp == "move":
            Move = input('Which door do you want to go through the door to the left or behind you?')
            if Move == "behind":
                Y = int(Y) - 1
            if Move == "left":
                X = int(X) - 1
            if Move == "right":
                X = int(X) + 1
    elif X == "1" and Y == "0":
        inp = input('You went down a spiral staircase and entered a dungeon. describe items, collect, move')
        if inp == "describe items":
            print('The room has a key, and two doors.')
        if inp == "collect":
            Icollect = input('Which item do you want to collect')
            if Icollect == "key":
                Slot = input('You have 5 inventory slots, which one do you want to put the key into?')
                Inventory[1] = 'key'
        if inp == "move":
            Move = input('Which door do you want to go through the door in front or to the right of you?')
            if Move == "front":
                Y = int(Y) + 1
            if Move == "right":
                X = int(X) + 1
```

I expected for the code to change the X and Y, and would move on to the other elif statements because that one is no longer true. The code changed the value but it never checking the other statements it was only checking the one if statement.

Comment: Either make `X` and `Y` ints *or* strings. Don't mix the two.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the strings(X and Y) into int's, so i didn't have to use the int(Y) thing and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are changing variable's type

```
X = "0"  
X = int(X) + 1
if X=="1":
   print("equals 1")
```

which is false because 
type(X) is int now